# Susskind Classical Mechanics The Theoretical Minimum - Issue with partial differentiation

Tags: derivatives, calculus

I've been reading Classical Mechanics - The Theoretical Minimum by Susskind and Hrabovsky.  On pg 83-84, I can't see why $F(x,y) = \sin x + \sin y$ should be a minimum at $x=\pi/2, y=\pi/2$.  Since $\sin (\pi/2) = 1$ then $F(x,y) = 2$ and values around this are lower than that so shouldn't it be a maximum? Or have I made a mistake somewhere?

[image: Page1]

[image: Page2]

Comment: Try to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/541298). Makes your math look so much better.

Comment: Thanks first time posting so still getting the hang of it.  I also noticed that the site has condensed one page to a link and the second is shown in full so not sure why those are different and apologies if it makes difficult to read

Comment: The text does not say "minimum", it says "stationary point" which applies to both minima _and_ maxima.

Answer (score 2):

It does appear to be a mistake as they fail to compare $D(x,y)=\sin(x)\sin(y)$ to $\partial^2f/\partial x^2$ at the same point (cf. the [second derivative test on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test) or [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html)). Since the latter term is clearly negative at $\pi/2$, then this function is indeed has a maximum at $(\pi/2,\,\pi/2)$.

The [plot of the figure](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+sin%28x%29%2Bsin%28y%29) clearly shows the function is a maximum at the desired point,
[image]
You can also request the min/max of the function on Wolfram Alpha (e.g., `maximize sin(x)+sin(y)`) which would return that $(x,\,y)=(2\pi n_1+\pi/2,\,2\pi n_2+\pi/2)$ for any integer $n_1,\,n_2$ (including 0!) would return the maximum of 2.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, yes I guess it's an error on their part. thanks